# Can we use "some X" when X is definite?

Tags: articles, determiners

Consider:

> Some men like doing housework.

Vs.

> We interviewed ten men. Some of the men liked doing housework.

Can one say "some men" in the second sentence?

Can I conclude when the noun x is definite we can't use "some x"? I think it's the case for other articles like "all" and "most", right? For example

> We interviewed ten men. Most of the men (not most men) liked doing housework.

We also can't say "some the men" can we?

Comment: @fumblefingers I don't think so., in that question I just asked about the use of "of" to separate "some x" but here I asked can we use "some x" for a definite x. They differ.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I read that question and its answers, they are different and that answer doesn't answer this question, so I changed the title of this question, please reconsider it.

Comment: @Andrew in the other question you said "some nodes" is acceptable even though I said the nodes are definite. Then I asked this question and still don't know its answer. Can we ever say "some nodes" when the nodes are specific? It's different from the old question as the duplicate of this.

Comment: That "some nodes" business relates to ANOTHER earlier question of yours ([“the most X” or “most of the X” in this sentence](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113135/)). Which I *haven't* cited as a duplicate, and on which I haven't posted any comments. In your example *here*, it's contextually obvious that *some, all, most, none* refers back to *ten men*, so you don't need to even mention that again. *We interviewed ten men. None liked doing housework.* is fine.

Comment: @fumblefingers good point! But it's just an example of a definite noun. So, if we want to repeat men "some men" is never the case. Right?

Comment: There is no grammatical rule against saying "We interviewed ten men. *Some men* liked peas, some did not".  It would be understood to mean "some of the ten men interviewed" even though that is not what it says. The language, knowing that it is being spoken by fallible human beings, allows for a great deal of what mechanical engineers call "slop".

Comment: @tromano ok that was the answer. It seems when the right choice is "some of the men" yet one can use "some men". I wanted to get sure about that and this question was for this purpose. Thank you.

Comment: The idiomatic choice is "some of them", often spoken "some of um".

Comment: @TRomano that is the choice, when "some" immediately follows the reference point and that is out of my question. Sometimes in the middle of text you can't say "some of them", you may want to look at http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113135/the-most-x-or-most-of-the-x-in-this-sentence

Answer (score 3):

You can't say "some men" in the second example, because using that will generalize the statement for all men, and not just the ones that attended the interview.

Saying "some of the men" makes sure that it is about a few of those that were actually interviewed.

Also, the word 'men' is being repeated. I'd rather prefer:

> "We interviewed ten men. Some of them liked housework."

This keeps the meaning intact, and makes sure there is no repitition.

Regarding,

> "some the men"

it is outright wrong.

Comment: I asked it in general, then you say never and in no context we can say "some x" when x is definite? Can you find any example which it's not the case?

Comment: +1. We would indeed say "Some of *them* ..." to refer back to the noun, rather than repeating the noun.